# How does instrumentation in profiling work?

Tags: c++, profiling, profiler, instrumentation

How does exactly instrumentation in profiling work?

What should I know to implement on my own a simple profiler which uses instrumentation?

Comment: What platform and OS?  For example, on some embedded systems, the instrumentation consists of writing pulses to test point pins and using oscilloscopes.  Others may use the *system tick* count.

Comment: Also, some compilers provide assistance with profile, such as the GNU compilers.

Comment: I assume you know the peculiarities of measuring duration of functions. You don't get line-level timing. You have to suspend measuring of a function when the same function is higher up on the call stack. The overhead of measuring duration can itself be dominant if you have small functions called a large number of times. If the reason for instrumentation is to get time including I/O, an alternative is simple wall-clock time sampling of the call stack. (An alarm-clock interrupt could do it - the frequency does not need to be high.)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews PC with linux or unix. It is not for embedded systems.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Unfortunately I don't know how to measure duration of functions.

Comment: If you're talking about adding entry/exit code to functions, to see how long they run, that's measuring duration.

Answer (score 0):

Instrumentation is extra code added (for example) around function bodies to record statistics such as the number of times the function is called and how long they take.  Details are completely dependent on the targeted profiler implementation.

In compiled languages, instrumentation normally needs to be introduced by the compiler and/or linker when the program or library is built.  As such, a general purpose profiler requires specific support in the compiler and / or linker.

In some other languages, it may be possible to introduce instrumentation at runtime via a mechanism specific to that language.